# How can I get prediction probabilities for a model with scikit learn framework hosted in Google AI platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scikit-learn, google-ai-platform

I have a model hosted in the AI platform which uses scikit-learn framework. I want to make predictions and also retrieve the prediction probabilities of each of the classes.
Example:

```
{
  "predictions": [
    {
      "label": "beach",
      "scores": [0.1, 0.9]
    },
    {
      "label": "car",
      "scores": [0.75, 0.25]
    }
  ]
}
```

In their [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/reference/rest/v1/projects/predict#response-examples), these scores are available for Tensorflow and custom prediction routines.
How I see if I use the custom prediction routine method, I would have to store the model in Google cloud storage and host it on another VM to make predictions. I would not prefer to do this and want to know if there is a method already available I can get the scores.

Comment: Unfortunately, There is no other way using scikit-learn than the custom prediction routine.

Comment: @JoseGutierrezPaliza thank you - would you know how can I retrieve prediction classes in the custom routine? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71481302/how-can-i-retrieve-the-prediction-class-in-google-custom-routine-on-ai-platform