# How can I retrieve the prediction class in google custom routine on AI platform?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, scikit-learn, google-ai-platform

For each instance, I want to retrieve the probability per prediction class.

I am building a custom prediction routine on Google AI platform:

```
import os
import joblib

class lr_predictor(object):

    def __init__(self,model):
        self._model = model

    def predict(self, instances, **kwargs):

        class_names = self._model.classes_
        if kwargs.get('probabilities'):
            probabilities = self._model.predict_proba(instances)
            return (class_names,probabilities.tolist())
        else:
            outputs = self._model.predict(instances)
            return outputs

    @classmethod
    def from_path(cls,model_dir):
        model_path = os.path.join(model_dir,'model.joblib')
        model = joblib.load(model_path)
        return cls(model)
```

How do I make this work?

Comment: Are you following the documentation as display on [Custom prediction routines](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines). It would be great of you can provide additional background or sample to understand what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Also, I think there is guide about prediciton routines on google sites [custom-prediction-routine-scikit-learn](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/notebooks/scikit-learn/custom-prediction-routine-scikit-learn.ipynb). Please let me know if it fits your scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A prediction class should follow the implementation defined on [Predictor Class](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines#predictor-class). This interface will tell AI-Platform how to handle prediction requests.

I have compile a list of official notebooks documentation that can guide you trough implementing a prediction class:

- [Custom Prediction Routines](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines)
- [Get started with Custom Prediction Routine](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/vertex-ai-samples/blob/8908b27b0897084962ef16bbfd894122287fb1a5/notebooks/community/ml_ops/stage6/get_started_with_cpr.ipynb)
- [Creating a custom prediction routine with scikit-learn](https://colab.sandbox.google.com/github/GoogleCloudPlatform/cloudml-samples/blob/master/notebooks/scikit-learn/custom-prediction-routine-scikit-learn.ipynb)

**Note**: Predictor class are later use to deploy a [custom prediction routine](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/custom-prediction-routines#deploy_your_custom_prediction_routine).